# How to set null for date form field in reactive form in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

How to set null for date filed in reactive form.I tried but not working.Anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="publishdate" ngbDatepicker #datepicker="ngbDatepicker">
```

app.component.ts:

```
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({}); 
this.registerForm.addControl('publishdate', new FormControl('', null));
```

Comment: Why aren't you declaring the date in the group function? Such as: this.registerForm = this.fb.group({publishdate: ['']});

Comment: Is this is your expectation? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-datepicker-validation-opt-out-vk6maq

Comment: @ManirajMurugan:  Yes..Got it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `input` be like

`<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="publishdate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">`

And so, the **HTML** should be like,

```
<form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="registerForm">
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="publishdate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
     <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
       </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

And **TS**,

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.registerForm.addControl('publishdate', new FormControl('', null));
  }
}
```

> **Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-datepicker-validation-opt-out-vk6maq

Comment: Can you answer this? I have lot of fileds ina form. But How can i reset particular fields ?  obj=['email','password','confirmPassword']; for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){ this.registerForm.controls[obj[i]].reset(); }

Comment: @NilaVaani, Please create stackblitz example and describe what your problem and I will try my best to solve..

Comment: Stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-e5gbvf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please check resetfn()

Comment: @NilaVaani, I will look into it and what is your expected result?

Comment: @NilaVaani, What are the fields you wish to reset??

Comment: If I click reset button then email, password, confirm password is getting resetted.. What is your expectation??

Comment: Yes.Working fine

Comment: I have one doubt in angular6/nodejs.Can u resolve it?

Comment: You know angular rite?

Comment: Can you try this to run? https://medium.com/@swapnilnakhate/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration-with-nodejs-f715e5fc25a

Comment: I do not know..how to run this..I think need to intergrate nodejs with angular 6

Comment: @NilaVaani, Nodejs is backend and did you built your current angular app with backend nodejs? Or anyother backend technologies?? If nodejs is backend then you can implement this..

Comment: Yes.I want to run this application?So How to do?

Comment: Back End (NodeJS) : https://github.com/SwapnilNakhate/PayUMoney-NodeJS.git
Front End (Angular 6) : https://github.com/SwapnilNakhate/PayUMoney-Angular6.git

Comment: @NilaVaani, I could not make this help right now and I am having my project work.. So you need to look at by yourself and try something and then post your question in SO what is your issue.. If you really need help then I can see it by tonight india time..

Comment: Also make sure you have every valid credentials for payumoney to proceed.. YOu cannot do anything as like that.. YOu should already have a valid credentials..

Comment: Yes..I have credentials details..I am from chennai india